# Vue js send data from api to new page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, vuejs3

I am new to Vue Js and I would like to know how I can send data between two components. I am building a vue app that gets a list of users from an api and displays them. I would like to know I can move data between two components so that I can view more details on a new page.

here is my html code to display the data in a table

```
        <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">ID</th>
              <th scope="col">Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Occupation</th>
              <th scope="col">Email</th>
              <th scope="col">Bio</th>
              <th scope="col">View</th>
              <th scope="col">Edit</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
              <th scope="row">{{ user.id }}</th>
              <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
              <td>{{ user.username}}</td>
              <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
              <td>{{ user.phonenumber}}</td>
              <router-link to="/users" class="btn btn-primary">View</router-link>
              </td>
              <td>
                <router-link @click="shareData" :key="user.id" to="/edit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</router-link>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

this is my js code

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";
import moment from "moment";

export default {
  name: 'Home',
created() {
    this.getUsers();
  },
  data() {
    return {
      users: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getUsers() {
      axios
        .get("https://607e868602a23c0017e8b79e.mockapi.io/api/v1/users")
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data);
          this.users = response.data;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
    format_date(value) {
      if (value) {
        return moment(String(value)).format("DD-MM-YYYY");
      }
    },
    shareData(){
    this.$router.push({name:"Users", params:{data:this.users}})
    },
    editData(){

    }
  },
};
```

where do how I move the data to the view and edit routes/components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use vue-router's [dynamic route matching](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html) for this kind of problem. You can simply refactor your `/user` endpoint to `/user/:id` and in the component you are calling when landing on `/user`, you can simply make your api call and fill in the details. You need to update your first router link to have some id in the form of: `/user/123` and in the component, you can get that id by calling `this.$route.params.id`.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the complexity of your Application, you may use [VUEX](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) to store all your Application's state, or if you have a small application and do want to spend time learning VUEX, you may simply use [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html). With props you can pass objects ( data ) to your components or even routes.

Comment: could you show me how to use vuex in this example? it would make it easier to understand

Comment: Here is a good example for you to follow:
https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/tree/dev/examples/shopping-cart

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass data from one sibling component to another sibling component ( components having same parent) then you can use **Event Bus**.

Here's an article which I used to learn  Event Bus [Event Bus Article](https://blog.logrocket.com/using-event-bus-in-vue-js-to-pass-data-between-components/)

If you want to **pass data from Parent component to child Component** , you can simply use a **props**.

If you want to get data anywhere in your code , then use **Vuex**.

Vuex sure is very handy. Happy learning.